# SQL CASE Single answer Yes or No

Tags: sql-server

I'm hoping you can help me, i'm trying to write a query is SQL to pull customer records from a booking to form a bookings list, all relatively simple information such as ID, Name, Booking Start Time etc.

I then wanted to add to that list if they had purchased a particular other single product before in the for of Yes/No.

I tried to accomplish this using a CASE statement

```
CASE WHEN ProductID = '1234' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'Authorised'
```

however it now bring up multiple records for each customer with the status of eash products the member has purchased in the past

Is there a way to just limit this to the product I am looking for? and ignore all other products?

Here's a sample of my query and data:

```
 SELECT

ID
, StartDateTime
, ActivityID
, ActivityName
, MaxBookees
, MemberID
, FirstNames
, CASE WHEN ProductID = '1234' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'Ignore' END AS 'Authorised'

FROM

Booking INNER JOIN
                         BookingCustomers ON Booking.ID = BookingCustomers.BookingID INNER JOIN
                         Members ON BookingCustomers.CustomerID = Customers.ID INNER JOIN
                         Activities ON Bookings.ActivityID = Activities.ID  RIGHT JOIN
                         Products ON Members.ID = Products.MemberID

WHERE        

(Booking.StartDateTime >= DATEADD(d, 0, GETDATE())) AND (Bookings.StartDateTime <= DATEADD(d, 7, GETDATE())) AND (BookingCustomers.MemberID > '0')
```

---

How it currently looks

```
ID  Start Date Time Activity ID Activity Name   Maximum Bookees Member ID   First Names Authorised
12345   07/12/2018 18:00    12345   Activity 1  8   1   John    NO
12345   07/12/2018 18:00    12345   Activity 1  8   1   John    NO
12345   07/12/2018 18:00    12345   Activity 1  8   2   James   YES
12345   07/12/2018 18:00    12345   Activity 1  8   2   James   NO
12345   07/12/2018 18:00    12345   Activity 1  8   3   Rose    NO
12346   07/12/2018 18:40    12346   Activity 1  8   4   Matthew NO
12347   07/12/2018 19:20    12347   Activity 2  8   5   Jonathan    YES
12348   07/12/2018 20:00    12348   Activity 3  8   6   Poppy   NO
12348   07/12/2018 20:00    12348   Activity 3  8   7   Katy    NO
12348   07/12/2018 20:00    12348   Activity 3  8   7   Katy    YES
12349   07/12/2018 20:40    12349   Activity 3  8   8   Nick    NO
```

How I want it to look

```
ID  Start Date Time Activity ID Activity Name   Maximum Bookees Member ID   First Names Authorised
12345   07/12/2018 18:00    12345   Activity 1  8   1   John    NO
12345   07/12/2018 18:00    12345   Activity 1  8   2   James   YES
12345   07/12/2018 18:00    12345   Activity 1  8   3   Rose    NO
12346   07/12/2018 18:40    12346   Activity 1  8   4   Matt    NO
12347   07/12/2018 19:20    12347   Activity 2  8   5   Jon YES
12348   07/12/2018 20:00    12348   Activity 3  8   6   Poppy   NO
12348   07/12/2018 20:00    12348   Activity 3  8   7   Katy    YES
12349   07/12/2018 20:40    12349   Activity 3  8   8   Nick    NO
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried add `DISTINCT`?

Comment: What is the logic by which one of the two yes/no pair of records gets retained or discarded?  Is there ever a case where a `NO` record would be retained?

Comment: Hi, Yes I tried a distinct but this didn't work.  Ideally I like to keep the NO's as if they are now then we need to identify them and turn them to a yes before they attend the activity.  If that makes sense?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns in your select clause, minus the `CASE` expression, seem to define a logical group.  That is, the "duplicate" yes/no record pairs appear have all the same values in these columns.  I suspect what you want to do here is to report `YES` if `ProductID = '1234'` occurs in any of the records for each group.  If so, we can `GROUP BY` the columns mentioned above, and use conditional aggregation to try to detect a matching `ProductID`.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    StartDateTime,
    ActivityID,
    ActivityName,
    MaxBookees,
    MemberID,
    FirstNames,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN ProductID = '1234' THEN 1 END) > 0
         THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS Authorised
FROM Booking b
INNER JOIN BookingCustomers bc
    ON b.ID = bc.BookingID
INNER JOIN Members m
    ON bc.CustomerID = bc.ID
INNER JOIN Activities a
    ON b.ActivityID = a.ID
LEFT JOIN Products p
    ON m.ID = p.MemberID
WHERE
    (Booking.StartDateTime >= DATEADD(d, 0, GETDATE())) AND
    (Bookings.StartDateTime <= DATEADD(d, 7, GETDATE())) AND
    (BookingCustomers.MemberID > '0')
GROUP BY
    ID,
    StartDateTime,
    ActivityID,
    ActivityName,
    MaxBookees,
    MemberID,
    FirstNames;
```

Comment: Thanks Tim,  This almost does what I'm after, however it's seemingly missing records I know are there for some reason, I'll have a play around and see if i can get this to work.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Lee That right join looks suspicious to me.  Why is it there?  Given your small testing data set, and the number of joins, I'm afraid this is the best I can do at the moment.

Comment: Funnily enough I just changed that right join to an inner, I think that was left from me playing about.

So I've figured out whats happening and its very nearly there with your query however where there are no product records at all for a customer its completely excluding them from results.  Is there a way to account for that in a CASE statement?

Comment: i.e. something like this: 

CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN ProductID = '1234' THEN 1 WHEN ProductID = IS NULL THEN 2 END) = 1 
         THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS Authorised

Comment: @Lee No, `COUNT` already can handle `NULL` values, and does so by not counting them.  Anyway, a `CASE` expression in the select statement can't be causing entire rows to disappear, so there must be some other reason.

Comment: You were right, the problem was the suspect RIGHT JOIN, I changed this to a LEFT JOIN and its now doing exactly what I want it to do, pulling all records and marking each one with Yes or No

Thank you for you help, very much appreciated.

Comment: Done! Sorry just getting the hang of things! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT

ID
, StartDateTime
, ActivityID
, ActivityName
, MaxBookees
, MemberID
, FirstNames
, CASE WHEN ProductID = '1234' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'Ignore' END AS 'Authorised'

FROM

Booking INNER JOIN
                         BookingCustomers ON Booking.ID = BookingCustomers.BookingID INNER JOIN
                         Members ON BookingCustomers.CustomerID = Customers.ID INNER JOIN
                         Activities ON Bookings.ActivityID = Activities.ID  RIGHT JOIN
                         Products ON Members.ID = Products.MemberID

WHERE        

(Booking.StartDateTime >= DATEADD(d, 0, GETDATE())) AND (Bookings.StartDateTime <= DATEADD(d, 7, GETDATE())) AND (BookingCustomers.MemberID > '0') AND Products.ProductId == '1234'
```

Add the filtering on products in your where clause. The where clause is meant for filtering search results like that. Adding distinct in conjunction with it can also help. You might want to finetune it but this will get you started.

Comment: Thanks Daan, I did try that initially however it then filters out the no's which i need to retain so we can take action against those records and turn them to Yes's.

Comment: Basically this query returns the row when the product id matches, which makes it a yes. you also want to return the fields that have no matching product ids. You could possible achieve this by using a subquery which checks if the id matches and if it does returns true, within an outer query that returns all rows.